# Retrieve tweets by username - twitter api

Tags: twitter

Can you display tweets of somebody else or is it just the account that you got the key and secret... etc details from?

I'm checking the params in [GET statuses/user_timeline docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-home_timeline) and I don't think I can!

I'm trying to build an app that allows you to display tweets by inputting a username of any account. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can get tweets of public users but if user is protected one then
>   his timelines may only be requested when the you either “own” the
>   timeline or are an approved follower of the protected user.

To get tweets from a specific user you will want to use the [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline) API method.

Just add `?screen_name=USERNAME` at the end of the endpoint. For example

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=username
```

This method can only return up to **3,200** of a user’s most recent Tweets.

Answer (score 4):

You can display another user's tweets even if you are not using their credentials. Basically, you can display anyone's public tweets if you know their screen name. This is the Twitter api request: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline

Answer (score 1):

This will only work for the user who has authenticated and is now using your app, as well as the users that they follow.

> Returns a collection of the most recent Tweets and Retweets posted by the authenticating user and the users they follow.

This is directly from the link you posted.